# Pandas throws weird exception when trying to apply function to duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicity

Why am I getting the following error message? I am trying to apply a function to a duplicate column. Please don't tell me that the solution is to do something like `df["a"] = 2 * df["a"]`; this is a dumbed down example of something more complicated I am working on right now.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [0,1,2], "b" : [1,2,3]})
>>> df[["a", "a"]].apply(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], axis = 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1980, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3332)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3035)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3955)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 169, in pandas.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates (pandas\index.c:4236)
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4061, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4157, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 583, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2000, in get_value
    raise IndexError(key)
IndexError: (0, 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: I tried there is no error it works maybe version problem.

Comment: Which version of python/pandas are you using? I'm using 3.5.1, pandas 0.18.1

Comment: Hmm, it appears to work under 2.7.11 and pandas 0.18.0.

Comment: yes python 2-7.10 and pandas 0.16.2, It may be a bug report it.

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13427

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you need change `x[0]` and `x['1']` to `x.a`, because there is no columns `0` and `1`:

```
a = df[["a", "a"]].apply(lambda x: x.a + x.a, axis = 1)
print (a)
   a  a
0  0  0
1  2  2
2  4  4
```

But if duplicity columns have different values use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [0,1,2], "b" : [1,2,3]})
df.columns = ['a','a']
print (df)
   a  a
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  2  3

df['sum'] = df.iloc[:,0] + df.iloc[:,1]
print (df)
   a  a  sum
0  0  1    1
1  1  2    3
2  2  3    5
```

What is same as:

```
df['sum'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] + x.iloc[1], axis = 1)
print (df)
   a  a  sum
0  0  1    1
1  1  2    3
2  2  3    5
```

Comment: Another workaround the author showed on the github page was to do df[['a','a']].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] + x.iloc[1], axis=1)